# Python: trace yields all function calls being __init__ and coming from __future__

Tags: python, trace

Using the trace module, for an app with many.many modules I get a very strange result, it tells me that every function I call is `__init__` and every module I call is `__future__`.

The call of the app looks like:

`python -m trace option foo |tee logfile`

where option is -t, -T, or -l.
-l generates no output.

The output for -t looks like:

```
foo(6): from __future__ import print_function
 --- modulename: __future__, funcname: <module>
__future__.py(48): """
__future__.py(51):     "nested_scopes",
__future__.py(52):     "generators",
__future__.py(53):     "division",
__future__.py(54):     "absolute_import",
__future__.py(55):     "with_statement",
__future__.py(56):     "print_function",
__future__.py(57):     "unicode_literals",
__future__.py(60): __all__ = ["all_feature_names"] + all_feature_names
__future__.py(66): CO_NESTED            = 0x0010   # nested_scopes
__future__.py(67): CO_GENERATOR_ALLOWED = 0        # generators (obsolete, was 0x1000)
__future__.py(68): CO_FUTURE_DIVISION   = 0x2000   # division
__future__.py(69): CO_FUTURE_ABSOLUTE_IMPORT = 0x4000 # perform absolute imports by default
__future__.py(70): CO_FUTURE_WITH_STATEMENT  = 0x8000   # with statement
__future__.py(71): CO_FUTURE_PRINT_FUNCTION  = 0x10000   # print function
__future__.py(72): CO_FUTURE_UNICODE_LITERALS = 0x20000 # unicode string literals
__future__.py(74): class _Feature:
 --- modulename: __future__, funcname: _Feature
__future__.py(74): class _Feature:
__future__.py(75):     def __init__(self, optionalRelease, mandatoryRelease, compiler_flag):
__future__.py(80):     def getOptionalRelease(self):
__future__.py(88):     def getMandatoryRelease(self):
__future__.py(97):     def __repr__(self):
__future__.py(102): nested_scopes = _Feature((2, 1, 0, "beta",  1),
__future__.py(103):                          (2, 2, 0, "alpha", 0),
__future__.py(104):                          CO_NESTED)
 --- modulename: __future__, funcname: __init__
__future__.py(76):         self.optional = optionalRelease
__future__.py(77):         self.mandatory = mandatoryRelease
__future__.py(78):         self.compiler_flag = compiler_flag
__future__.py(106): generators = _Feature((2, 2, 0, "alpha", 1),
__future__.py(107):                       (2, 3, 0, "final", 0),
__future__.py(108):                       CO_GENERATOR_ALLOWED)
 --- modulename: __future__, funcname: __init__
__future__.py(76):         self.optional = optionalRelease
__future__.py(77):         self.mandatory = mandatoryRelease
__future__.py(78):         self.compiler_flag = compiler_flag
__future__.py(110): division = _Feature((2, 2, 0, "alpha", 2),
__future__.py(111):                     (3, 0, 0, "alpha", 0),
__future__.py(112):                     CO_FUTURE_DIVISION)
 --- modulename: __future__, funcname: __init__
__future__.py(76):         self.optional = optionalRelease
__future__.py(77):         self.mandatory = mandatoryRelease
__future__.py(78):         self.compiler_flag = compiler_flag
__future__.py(114): absolute_import = _Feature((2, 5, 0, "alpha", 1),
__future__.py(115):                            (3, 0, 0, "alpha", 0),
__future__.py(116):                            CO_FUTURE_ABSOLUTE_IMPORT)
 --- modulename: __future__, funcname: __init__
__future__.py(76):         self.optional = optionalRelease
__future__.py(77):         self.mandatory = mandatoryRelease
__future__.py(78):         self.compiler_flag = compiler_flag
__future__.py(118): with_statement = _Feature((2, 5, 0, "alpha", 1),
__future__.py(119):                           (2, 6, 0, "alpha", 0),
__future__.py(120):                           CO_FUTURE_WITH_STATEMENT)
 --- modulename: __future__, funcname: __init__
__future__.py(76):         self.optional = optionalRelease
__future__.py(77):         self.mandatory = mandatoryRelease
__future__.py(78):         self.compiler_flag = compiler_flag
__future__.py(122): print_function = _Feature((2, 6, 0, "alpha", 2),
__future__.py(123):                           (3, 0, 0, "alpha", 0),
__future__.py(124):                           CO_FUTURE_PRINT_FUNCTION)
 --- modulename: __future__, funcname: __init__
__future__.py(76):         self.optional = optionalRelease
__future__.py(77):         self.mandatory = mandatoryRelease
__future__.py(78):         self.compiler_flag = compiler_flag
__future__.py(126): unicode_literals = _Feature((2, 6, 0, "alpha", 2),
__future__.py(127): ...
```

-T generates similar output with all functions `__init__` called from module `__future__`.
How can I generate a decent trace of the program?

Comment: Importing a module causes it to be evaluated (assuming it's not already been imported). What makes you think this is wrong? You see repeated calls to __init__() probably because it's instantiating several objects of the same type.

Comment: Well the very first thing is that I do not have a module called `__future__`. The second thing despit the fact that I know there are many other modules used and functions called, I see none of them. The third is, if everything is correct and this is what happens all the time then the module trace would be useless.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion, that the future calls are detritus from pythin internals, but that leaves the question: where is the rest? Does the python trace module, for example, only descend so low in nested function calls and future eats them up. If so how can I increase the nesting level?

Comment: The output from `trace` is **very** long.  This prefix is simply not representative.